Wordpress страница появилась, но загрузка продолжается и кнопки не работают
Я использую Wordpress и конструктор Elementor. Страница почти всегда быстро загружается и все работает, но иногда случается так, что контент появился, но страница продолжают грузиться, а кнопки и анимации не работают. пример:

На скрине видно, что сайт отобразился, но загрузка продолжается. Так она может продолжаться очень длительное время.
Подскажите, что делать с такой проблемой. Также я заметил, что чаще всего такая ошибка появляется на страницах, где есть вставленное видео youtube без отложенной загрузки, но случается и с обычными страницами

Открываете инструменты разработчика, переходите на вкладку Network и смотрите что же там продолжает грузиться.
